# Will there be change in electronegativity difference in C-O and C=O?

Tags: bond, electronegativity, dipole

Is there any change in EN difference in C-O and C=O. If yes, why?
Does EN difference change if its bond is changed to single, double, or triple?

Comment: " its bond" that of the C-O or C=O?

Comment: s - character is proportional to electronegativity. In single, double and triple bonds, there is difference in s - character (triple bond > double > single) due to the participating hybridised orbitals of C, and hence difference in electronegativity.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I think that you didn't understand the answer to [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/98019/why-does-c-o-have-a-larger-dipole-moment-than-c-o).

A dipole is created when two equal (only in magnitude) and opposite charges are separated by some distance. The dipole moment depends on the magnitude of the charges and the distance between them. Electronegativity is just a concept that helps us to get an idea of the magnitude of the charges. So, in order to find the dipole moment, you should focus on the magnitude of the two charges rather than the electronegativity difference.

Look at the hybridization of the atoms in the single and double bond. That will tell you that both the atoms should be more electronegative after forming a double bond, but won't help you comment on the electronegativity difference.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78618/discussion-on-answer-by-anurag-baundwal-will-there-be-change-in-electronegativit).